# CSS - allow div to extend beyond overflow-hidden ancestor

Tags: html, css

In my HTML, I've got a `<div>` that I would like to allow to overflow its great-great-great-grandparent - basically, the ancestor is a menu item container, and when a menu item (the parent of the `<div>` in question) is clicked, the `<div>` will open and occupy all of the space that it needs, which is likely to overflow all of its ancestors.  Ok, first some pictures to help...

Here's what I'd like to see - the blue 'Menu content' `<div>` overflows the yellow g-g-g-grandparent into the whitespace to the right:

[image]

However, despite my best efforts, all I can actually get is this:

[image]

so the blue is cut off at the edge of the yellow.

Here's the HTML/CSS for what I've got so far (some may be irrelevant, but I'm making sure to include everything):

```
#nav-settings-wrapper{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#nav-content-container{
    height: 80%;
    min-height: 475px;
    min-width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}

#nav-settings{
    margin: 90px 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white
}

#nav-settings__item{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0097D8;
}

#dropdown{
    position: relative;
    color: black;
}

#dropdown-menu{
    width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

<div id="nav-settings-wrapper">
    <div id="nav-content-container">
        <div id="nav-settings">
            <div id="nav-settings__item">
                <div id="dropdown">
                    Menu item
                    <div id="dropdown-menu">
                        Menu content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In doing some experiments, I did find that turning off both `overflow` properties of the g-g-g-grandparent did allow for this behavior (albeit with some other problems), but turning them off is not really an option - I need to allow for overflow-y, and allowing overflow-x keeps the blue 'inside' of the yellow and allows me to scroll to the side - not what I need...

I'm not really a design guy and this is a project that I'm picking up in the middle, so any guidance as to how I can get my elements to behave like the first image would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not possible. Like in real life, a child cannot ignore the rules of its great-grandparent unless it's dead. Unfortunately, html elements don't die this easily :-D.